# Creating custom cocoa UI Controls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Use-case:
 1. Create a **'.XiB' based** UI control consisting of several basic UI elements
 2. Embed the control @ [1] in eg. a UIViewController

With C#/.NET it is possible to create WinForm controls with specialized UI and then to embed them in other controls, is there an equivalent in Cocoa @ iPhone ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `UIView` on one of xib views, select it and go to Identity Inspector and change the class to yours:

[image]

Note, with this approach the custom view is not drawn at Xib editor, you'll see it as `UIView` there. You'll want to prepare the outlets for the custom view "several basic UI elements".

Comment: How do I associated the view with the Xib file ( so the child elements will get created ) ?

Comment: Found it, [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed]